# Force index.php have_posts() loop to exit if no sticky posts found

Tags: theme-development, loop

I'm currently using the code below to list sticky posts on my index.php.

However, when no sticky posts are present, its loading the latest posts (up to the number specified in "settings > reading > blog posts show at most *_* posts".

How can I alter the script so that if there are no sticky posts, it exits out of the while?

```
query_posts(array('post__in'=>get_option('sticky_posts')));

if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `get_option` will return an empty array if there are no sticky posts and the query will default to everything.

```
$sticky = get_option('sticky_posts');
if (!empty($sticky)) {
  $args['post__in'] = $sticky;
  $qry = new WP_Query(array('post__in' => $sticky));
  if ($qry->have_posts()) :
    while ($qry->have_posts()) : $qry->the_post();
      echo $post->post_title;
    endwhile;
  endif;
}
```

And please don't use `query_posts`.

Comment: Oh, and as yet another aside, +1 to you and Mr. Scholz, obviously (I ain't in no competition). Good night.

Answer (score 3):

Ask for the existence of sticky posts, *before* you query the database:

```
$stickies = get_option('sticky_posts');

if ( $stickies )
{
    // fetch posts
}
```

And please read [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) :)

Answer (score 0):

For starters, before we get to the essential issue, there is <del>never</del> **hardly ever** a reason to use `query_posts`. It should be treated as if deprecated - mostly anyway.

It does not reset, but overwrite the main query *after* that has already been executed anyway.

Much rather, use either the [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) function or a new instance of the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class:

```
$args = array(
    'post__in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

$stickies = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $stickies->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $stickies->have_posts() ) {
        $stickies->the_post();
        // do something
    }
}

// reset the $post global to its previous state
wp_reset_postdata();
```

If, regardless of whether sticky posts were found, you'd like to alter the main query to return nothing (on the home page), make use of the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action:

```
function wpse_96219_nothing_on_home( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 0 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_96219_nothing_on_home' );
```

Comment: This solution has the same problem as noted in the question-- "when no sticky posts are present, its loading the latest posts". I tested it. `$stickies` will have posts, but if there are no "sticky" post those posts will be the most recent ones.

Comment: For real, @s_ha_dum? Granted, I *did not test this* and wrote it up as the last deed of the day before hitting the pillow - but with `pre_get_posts` in place and returning void when on the main blog page - shouldn't that do it?

Comment: What's the logic behind the function name? Are the numbers just a way to reduce the chances of the same name being used elsewhere?

Comment: @s_ha_dum I suppose I was thinking "filter" when I mistakenly thought returning nothing would suffice. Anyhoo, I altered it to what I *believe* should now do it, which, given yours and toschos answer is somewhat redundant, but what the hell - hurt, it can't. And as a sidenote, Dominic, yes, the function name is simply meant to reduce chance of causing conflict when verbosely copied.